# ASP.Net 4 session data missing with Safari 5.1.5

Tags: asp.net, session, safari

I am having a strange issue with Safari 5.1.5, I have an ASP.NET page (version 4) that is making use of a wziard control. On a particular step of the wizard I am collecting information, the user is required to click a link button which performs a postback and populates a datagrid on the same step of the Wizard.

The data is loaded into a dataset and the databind is working fine and information is displayed on the page. Along with this the dataset is loaded into a session object for use later in the wizard.

When the user is finished on this particular step the next button (on the wizard) is clicked and a check is performed to make sure that ample information is provided. This is done by retrieving the dataset from the session object and the relevant table is interrogated.

In Google Chrome, IE and Opera this works fine and the dataset is retrieved and the data exists. However in Safari 5.1.5 and Firefox 14 the dataset is empty. Exactly the same code is run for all browsers.

I have stepped through the code in using both Google and Safari and when in Safari the datatable of the dataset is empty even though it was used to populate the datagrid.

I though perhaps that the dataset was being corrupted before being loaded into the session object, but I have tested this by retrieving the dataset from the session immediately after is was assigned to the session variable and then serializing the dataset to XML. The XML file shows that the information was loaded into the datatable and into the session.

Has anyone seen behaviour like this before or have any suggestions as to where to go from here.

Thanks in advance
Glen.

**SOLVED:** 
The problem was that Safari was doing a double postback, the first time was correct but the second time it was doing a postback with viewstate info and therefore the IsPostBack was false and the session variables were being initialized again.

Comment: Weird behavior indeed. Have you tired simpler session data like a string? Is that lost too? Sessions are tied to the browser using cookies, check if your cookies are being passed correctly.

Comment: could you elaborate on how you solved this?  I think I may be having the same problem :/

Answer (score 0):

Please check if cookies are enabled. Since cookies holde session id, you should enable them.

Or you can set cookieless=true at sessionState of web config.